# How can I use one column to determine where I get the value for another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to use one column to determine which column to use as the value for another column  It looks something like this:

```
     X   Y  Z   Target
1    a   b  c    X
2    d   e  f    Y
3    g   h  i    Z
```

And I want something that looks like this:

```
     X   Y  Z   Target  TargetValue
1    a   b  c    X           a
2    d   e  f    Y           e
3    g   h  i    Z           i
```

Where each TargetValue is the value determined by the column specified by Target.  I've been using dplyr a bit to get this to work.  If I knew how to make the output of paste the input for mutate that would be great,

```
mutate(TargetWordFixed = (paste("WordMove",TargetWord,".rt", sep="")))
```

but maybe there is another way to do the same thing.

Be gentle, I'm new to both stackoverflow and R...

Comment: A simple solution: `df$target<-diag(as.matrix(df[,1:3]))`?

Comment: @Metrics, that is just by chance the right solution here but not the answer since it doesn't refer to what's written in the target value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized approach would be to use matrix subsetting:

```
df %>% mutate(TargetValue = .[cbind(1:n(), match(Target, names(.)))])
#  X Y Z Target TargetValue
#1 a b c      X           a
#2 d e f      Y           e
#3 g h i      Z           i
```

Or just using base R (same approach):

```
transform(df, TargetValue = df[cbind(1:nrow(df), match(Target, names(df)))])
```

Explanation:

- `match(Target, names(.))` computes the column indices of the entries in Target (which column is called X etc)
- The `.` in the dplyr version refers to the data you "pipe" into the mutate statement with `%>%` (i.e. it refers to `df`)
- `df[cbind(1:n(), match(Target, names(df))]` creates a matrix to subset df to the correct values - the first column of the matrix is just the row numbers starting from 1 to the number of rows of df (therefore `1:nrow(df)`) and the second column in the matrix is the index which column holds the Target value of interest (computed by `match(Target, names(df))`).

The matrix that is produced for subsetting the example data is:

```
cbind(1:nrow(df), match(df$Target, names(df)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    3
```

Comment: I need to spend a bit of time catching up on what all of that did, but the mutate function you gave me is working exactly as intended.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoeJalbert, sure, it looks complicated at first. I tried to give you at least some hints in the brief explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `apply` rowwise like this:

```
transform(df, TargetValue = apply(df, 1, function(x) x[x["Target"]]))
#   X Y Z Target TargetValue
# 1 a b c      X           a
# 2 d e f      Y           e
# 3 g h i      Z           i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-setNames(data.frame(cbind(matrix(letters[1:9],3,3,byrow=T), c("X", "Y", "Z"))), c("X", "Y", "Z", "Target"))

df

df %>% 
  gather(key="ID", value="TargetValue", X:Z) %>%
  filter(ID==Target) %>%
  select(Target, TargetValue) %>%
  left_join(df, by="Target")
```